# Android Custom Array Adapter to read CSV files

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, csv

I am a newbie to android application development. I am currently working on a project which deals with the import of csv files which consists of only one column and many rows , onto my android project. I am able to read those csv files onto my project using csv adapters and array adapters and I didn't use any string arrays. Only used csvadapter and array adapters. Now in the list view where all the csv datas are presented, I am having a concern where when clicked on an item in the list I wanted to toast the item name. I tried out all possible combinations but it displays me only a toast saying string@somerandomvalue. Request someone to help me on this. Thanks in advance.

The following is my csvadapter class. The .csv files are in placed in assets folder..

```
public class CSVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<clock>{
    Context ctx;
    public CSVAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId)
    {
        super (context,textViewResourceId);
        this.ctx = context;
        loadArrayFromFile();
    }
    @Override
public View getView(final int pos,View convertView,final ViewGroup parent){
    TextView mView=(TextView)convertView;
    if(null == mView){
        mView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        mView.setTextSize(28);
    }
    mView.setText(getItem(pos).getTime());
    return mView;
}
```

And this is my class to read that .csv array into GUI

```
public class mrvtoparanur extends Activity {
CSVAdapter mAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mrvtoparanur);
      final ListView mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mrvtoparanurlist);
      mAdapter=new CSVAdapter(this,-1);
      mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);   
      mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
      {
          @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you selected item number"+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }});
}
```

**Request someone to help on the Toast in the second class java file. In the msg "YOU SELECTED ITEM NUMBER" the arg2 gives the item id.. In a similar way i want to display or toast the item name instead of item ID. Pls help me someone**

This is clock.java file... Please refer below.

```
 public class clock {
    private String t;

    public String getTime() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setTime(String t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the data from the adapter:

```
clock clicked = mAdapter.getItem(arg2);
```

(Then I don't know the structure of the `clock` object)

Comment: hi..thanks for your immediate reply. But your code is giving me the following toast message  your selected item number com.mrvshuttle.clock@43e5b588 ..

Comment: According to your edit, you probably want to toast `clicked.getTime()`, basically like you did in the adapter.getView.

Comment: marvellous brother  ! Works like charm! A million thanks ! :D

Comment: now i have a small doubt. will i be able to split one single item from the array ? and also if i want to split that one item to each letter or number. Say the item has 11:23 .. i want to split 11 and 23 and save them in two different integer variables...can we do that ?

Comment: you can use `String.split()`: `String[] res = "11:23".split(":");` res[0] is "11" res[1] is "23". Then you need to use `Integer.parseInt(String)` on each value. `int hours = Integer.parseInt(res[0]); int minutes = Integer.parseInt(res[1]);`